# how to use xlrd module with python for abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm working on a script for abaqus where I have to import data from an excel file to put them into my script.
I already downloaded the xlrd module and it work well on python interpreter (IDLE), but when I put the line `import xlrd` in the script in abaqus PDE an error pop:

```
no module named xlrd
```

I think that the problem is that the xlrd module is installed, but abaqus use only default modules when it works, so I have to add the module xlrd for abaqus manually, how can I do this?
I'm using python 3.5.x, should I change for an older version 2.7.x?
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abaqus Python uses its own Python interpreter. The Version of the Python interpreter depends on wich version of Abaqus you use (2.6 or 2.7 for newer Abaqus versions).

Keep also in mind that the compiler versions differs from normal CPython. On Windows this will cause problems if you want to install pre-compiled modules. So you have to build and install the needed modules yourself.

On a module wich consits only of Python code like xlrd this is quite easy. Download the source code and unpack it. Open a command window in the folder where the setup.py of the module is located and type

```
abaqus python setup.py install
```

Comment: @SergeyFomin Which abaqus version and which platform (Windows/ Linux)?

Comment: it is necessary to install setuptools first

Comment: @SergeyFomin Yes it is. Do you get it to work. You would need MSC v.1700 to do that.

Comment: import xlrd was successful

Answer (score 1):

You can add path to `sys.path` where it can find `xlrd` package.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/harsh/.virtualenvs/abc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
import xlrd
```

Happy Coding.